# Knuth Morris Pratt application no error but not working

Tags: java, android, arraylist, knuth-morris-pratt

Here's my application

"Textform", take value from the searchbox.

"listKamus", take value from the array. Then "player name", change it value to string.

"KMP.knutMorris(textform, playerName)", send textform, playerName value to knutMorris class

MAIN CLASS

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
{
    String textform = s.toString();
    searchResults.clear();

    for(int i=0;i<listKamus.size();i++)
       {
      String playerName=listKamus.get(i).toString();
      KMP.knutMorris(textform, playerName);
        if(KMP.value==1){
        searchResults.add(listKamus.get(i));
        }
        }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

KMP CLASS

```
public class KMP {

/** Failure array **/

private int[] failure;
public static int value;

/** Constructor **/

public KMP(String text, String pat)

{

/** pre construct failure array for a pattern **/

failure = new int[pat.length()];

fail(pat);

/** find match **/

int pos = posMatch(text, pat);

if (pos >= 0)
{
KMP.value = 1;
}
}

/** Failure function for a pattern **/

private void fail(String pat)

{

int n = pat.length();

failure[0] = -1;

for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)

{

    int i = failure[j - 1];

    while ((pat.charAt(j) != pat.charAt(i + 1)) && i >= 0)

        i = failure[i];

    if (pat.charAt(j) == pat.charAt(i + 1))

        failure[j] = i + 1;

    else

        failure[j] = -1;

}

}

/** Function to find match for a pattern **/

private int posMatch(String text, String pat)

{

int i = 0, j = 0;

int lens = text.length();

int lenp = pat.length();

while (i < lens && j < lenp)

{

    if (text.charAt(i) == pat.charAt(j))

    {

        i++;

        j++;

    }

    else if (j == 0)

        i++;

    else

        j = failure[j - 1] + 1;

}

return ((j == lenp) ? (i - lenp) : -1);

}

/** Main Function **/

public static void knutMorris(String textform, String isidatabase)

{

String text = textform;

String pattern = isidatabase;

KMP kmp = new KMP(text, pattern);        

}
```

I want when people type on the searchbox it shows the right list of array.

I think the error one is here

MAIN CLASS

```
 if(KMP.value==1){
        searchResults.add(listKamus.get(i));
        }
```

Or here

KMP CLASS

```
if (pos >= 0)
{
KMP.value = 1;
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this ?